# Jqgrid does not show checkbox column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-core-3.1

I am adding jqGrid table in my .net core project.

I want to show first column of my table as checkbox. (Header and rows with checkbox)

Content of test.cshtml page

```
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="~/lib/bootstrap4-toggle/css/bootstrap4-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Files for jqgrid-->
    <link href="~/lib/jqueryui/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/lib/jqgrid/css/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="icon" href="~/image/logoTitle.png" />
    <link href="~/css/myCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>
    <div>
       <table id="jqGrid"></table>
       <div id="jqControls"></div
    </div>

    <script src="~/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap4-toggle/js/bootstrap4-toggle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

    <script src="~/lib/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jqgrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-ja.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jqueryui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Content of tets.ts file

```
interface JQuery {
    [x: string]: any;
    jqGrid: any;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
        url: "./GetData",
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'Get',
        multiselect: true,
        colNames: ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'],
        colModel: [
            { key: false,name:'Col1',index:'Col1',editable:true,sortable:true,width:'100px',search: false,align:'center'},
            { key:false,name:'Col2',index:'Col2',editable:true,sortable:true,width:'120px',search: false,align:'center'},
            { key:false,name:'Col3',index: 'Col3',editable:true,sortable:true,width:'100px',search: false,align:'center'}
        ],
        pager: jQuery('#jqControls'),
        rowNum: 20,
        rowList: ['10', '20', '30', '40', 'All'],
        height: 600,
        viewrecords: true,
        sortname: 'Col1',
        sortorder: 'desc',
        caption: '',
        emptyrecords: '',
        jsonReader: {
            root: "rows",
            page: "page",
            total: "total",
            records: "records",
            repeatitems: false,
            Id: "0"
        },
        autowidth: true,
        beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
            // Disable row selection
            return false;
        },
        onCellSelect: function (rowid, iCol, cellcontent, e) {
            // Handle Add, Edit, Delete action
            //handleAction(rowid, iCol, cellcontent, e);
        },
        onSortCol: function (index, iCol, sort) {
            // set current page number
            //jQuery("#jqGrid").setGridParam({ page: PageNumber });
        },
        loadComplete: function (data) {
            // save current page number
            PageNumber = data.page;
            // error handling
            if (data.success === false) {
            }
        }
    });
    $(".ui-jqgrid-titlebar").hide(); function () { fnBeforeSearch(); } });
});
```

using above source code all tables columns are visible on browser but checkbox's are not visible.
I have Inspect the jqGrid table and result is as below.

Image1: When checkbox is not visible on browser

[image]

Image2: Manually updated the input type to button
[image]

Additional Information:
Browser: Edge

JQGrid: jqGrid JS - v5.4.0

jqueriui: jQuery UI - v1.12.1

Answer (score 0):

You do a totally mismatch in your code - you use the css file from dataTables and the javascript from jqGrid. In order to see the checkboxes you will need to clarify which plugin you will use - dataTables or jqGrid.

If you want to use  Guriddo jqGrid, please read the docs on how to use correct your grid. See [here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/#installation)

Comment: I have confused with various version of jqgrid. 1. free-jqgrid 2. jqgrid 3. Guriddo jqgrid.
Guriddo jqgrid is paid license version. just want to confirm that is it possible to show checkbox column in free-jqgrid or jqgrid. If possible can you suggest me what line should i delete from my existing source code to support jqgrid part only. (I have updated the css import part)

Comment: The version you use (as described from you)  is paid. If you are licensed user, please connect to the support team of the product. If you are not licensed user you can connect the support of Guriddo jqGrid too. Before to use any product it is recommended to read the basicof of it. - I have point it to it in my previous comment. To see various features of Guriddo you can visit [our demo](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/). The  see multiselection see [this demo](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/selection/checkbox/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for reply...!
Existing problem was occurred because of faulty css style set for checbox because of which it wasn't display on browser. Thanks for support.